# Difference between win32 dll and .net dll in the context of web application?

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, web-applications, xbap

My web application, written in WPF( XBAP), p/invokes a win32 dll (`player.dll` written in C and C++). I deployed the application. When I tried running the web-application in IE, initially I got this error:

> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to
>   load DLL 'Player.dll': The specified
>   module could not be found. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

But when I manually copied my *win32* dll to `C:\Windows\System32` of the client PC, it worked, even though my web application uses several other .Net dlls and I didn't copy them manually.

So I'm confused as to why exactly do I need to copy **only** win32 dll to the client PC, while not .Net dlls? Do web-applications access them differently?

--

The related topic is this :

[DllNotFoundException when web application p/invokes a win32 DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790823/dllnotfoundexception-when-web-application-p-invokes-a-win32-dll)

Answer (score 1):

The rules to locate assemblies (.NET) are not the same as for locating native DLLs. Here are the two rule sets:

- Assemblies: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf.aspx
- Win32 DLLs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: By "native DLLs", you mean those dlls which come with the OS or/and Visual studio? Does it also include the ones which I create myself in VC++?

Comment: By native DLLs, I mean any non .NET assembly DLLs. Native DLLs export functions and data, as well as resources. Examples are system components, such as User32.dll and also DLLs you build with VisualC++. Assemblies, on the other hand, don't export anything (the export table is empty). These are special (non native) DLLs for use by the CLR, and which you can use from any .NET language.